Issue with acquireTokenSilent: Always Returning 'No accounts available' in React App Using MSAL
I am working on a React.js application where I have implemented authentication using MSAL. The login flow is working fine, and I am able to retrieve the redirect URI after a successful login.
However, when trying to fetch user data using acquireTokenSilent, I am consistently getting the message 'No accounts available.' even though the login process seems to complete successfully. Below is a snippet of my code:

const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        console.log("Accounts:", accounts);
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            try {
                const accessTokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                    scopes: ['User.Read.All'],
                    account: accounts[0]
                });

                const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessTokenResponse.accessToken}`,
                    },
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                setUser(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('No accounts available.');
        }
    };

    fetchUserData();
}, [accounts, instance]);


The console consistently logs 'No accounts available.' right after login, even though I expect accounts to have the authenticated user's data.
What might be causing this issue, and how can I successfully fetch the token and user data?

I verified that the login flow was working correctly and that I was being redirected to the correct URI after successful authentication.
Sucess URL http://localhost:3000#code=0.XXX.YYY&client_info=CCC&state=SSSS&session_state=SSSSUUU
I used console.log to inspect the accounts object and confirmed that it is always empty, leading to the message 'No accounts available.'.
I tried to debug the issue by ensuring that the MSAL configuration is correct and that the login redirect method is properly executed.


Are you trying to get the User Data like this.

Yes, this is what is expected.

When I used the scope as User.Read.All in the code, I couldn't fetch the User data from Azure. So, I changed the scope to User.Read to read the User Data and added a logout function that redirects the user after logging out.
Below is the modified complete code with the scope and logout code.
src/App.js :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './components/AuthButton';
import { authConfig } from './config/Config';

function App() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      console.log("Accounts:", accounts);
      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        try {
          const accessTokenResponse = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: ['User.Read'],
            account: accounts[0],
          });
          const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessTokenResponse.accessToken}`,
            },
          });
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
          }
          const data = await response.json();
          setUser(data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('No accounts available.');
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, [accounts, instance]);

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await instance.logoutRedirect({
        postLogoutRedirectUri: authConfig.auth.redirectUri,
        mainWindowRedirect: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>My React App</h1>
        {accounts.length === 0 ? (
          <AuthButton msalInstance={instance} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome, {accounts[0].username}</p>
            <p>User Data: {user ? JSON.stringify(user) : 'Loading...'}</p>
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

src/components/AuthButton.js :
import React from 'react';
function AuthButton({ msalInstance }) {
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        prompt: 'select_account',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AuthButton;

src/config/Config.js :
export const authConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: '<clientID>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
    system: {
      allowNativeBroker: false,
    },
  };

src/index.js :
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { authConfig } from './config/Config';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(authConfig);
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Output :
I successfully logged in by clicking on Login button below,

I got the User Data after logging in as shown below,

I logged out by clicking Logout button below.


its going to console.log('No accounts available.'); but login was success
